# pyspark java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after dropna()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException after performing dropna() on a frame. I am working on spark 1.6.0 in local mode.

```
frame.count()
```

30362

```
f = frame.dropna()
f.show()
```

Works fine returns the rows

but if I do

```
f.count()
```

I get the error below:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-54-5ecf758fc9ff> in <module>()
----> 1 f.count()

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in count(self)
    266         2
    267         """
--> 268         return int(self._jdf.count())
    269 
    270     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
    536         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
    537         return_value = get_return_value(answer, self.gateway_client,
--> 538                 self.target_id, self.name)
    539 
    540         for temp_arg in temp_args:

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     34     def deco(*a, **kw):
     35         try:
---> 36             return f(*a, **kw)
     37         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     38             s = e.java_exception.toString()

/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    298                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    299                     'An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n'.
--> 300                     format(target_id, '.', name), value)
    301             else:
    302                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o125.count.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 52.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 52.0 (TID 40, localhost): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1280)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1493)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1455)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1813)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1826)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1839)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1910)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:905)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:904)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:1386)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withNewExecutionId(DataFrame.scala:1904)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.collect(DataFrame.scala:1385)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.count(DataFrame.scala:1403)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Comment: Isn't `df.na.drop`? And did you do anything before?

Comment: dropna and na.drop are alias. I did a withColumn operation before this. Also  I actually want to do a groupby and that is failing with the same error. I searched online and found that it may be cause due to some null records, hence I did dropna.

Comment: It turns out that the very last line of the dataset was malformed, I expected dropna() to remove any malformed row, but getting rid of the row manually in rdd, got rid of the problem.